# Reading a cookie that has just been written causes the cookie to be blanked

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, cookies

Okay so this one has me stumped.  I have written a function that reads the value of a cookie.  The logic is

- check Response.Cookies in case it has just been written
- otherwise read from Request.Cookies to get the previous value

If the cookie has just been written then all is good, and I get the value.  However if the cookie has not been written on this visit - it appears to blank the value of the already store cookie.

What?

Here is the code

**Note the write happens in a controller**

```
public static void PersistCookie(string cookieName, string cookieValue, bool persistent)
{
    var cookie = new HttpCookie(cookieName, cookieValue)
    {
        Path = "/",
        HttpOnly = true,
    };

    if (persistent)
        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(6);

    HttpContext.Current.Response.SetCookie(cookie);
}
```

**Note the read happens ina partial view**

```
public static string ReadCookieValue(string cookieName, bool checkResponseFirst)
{
    if (checkResponseFirst && HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies[cookieName] != null &&
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies[cookieName].Value.HasValue())
            return HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies[cookieName].Value;

    return HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[cookieName] != null ? HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[cookieName].Value : "";
}
```

It almost seems that just by checking if a cookie has a value, it messes things up.

Thoughts?

Comment: Are you maybe calling ReadCookieValue from a partial view or through Ajax?

Comment: Have you tried `HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Get` instead of using `[]`?

Comment: Can you paste the code snippet where you are setting the cookie in your response? Also, what is the expected behavior of this function if you want to clear the cookie?

Comment: @Andreas - yes indeed I am calling it from a Partial view - why does that matter?

Comment: @Doug I have included the writing of the cookie in the original question now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay so after much more searching on the web, a good work colleague cam up with the following

it looks like I have come across a curiosity in .NET.

Check out this article

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3106/On-The-Care-and-Handling-of-Cookies

> If you try to access a cookie that doesn't exist in the Response.Cookies collection, it will be created with an empty string in the Value and an Expires date of 01-Jan-0001 00:00. Strangely, it also creates a matching cookie in the Request.Cookies collection if one doesn't already exist.
>
> So if you look at a cookie in the Response then you are indirectly overwriting the cookie on the client machine with an empty cookie, due to expire when the browser closes

So my problem is solved (or should that be unsolvable).  As it turns out I have a workaround using the ViewBag but I am glad I was not going crazy!

Thanks for you help

Comment: Late on the game, but you could have used HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains() to first check if the cookie was set or not.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure you can set cookies in partial views. When setting the cookie with Response.SetCookie, the information is returned to the browser in the Set-Cookie HTTPHeader field. I don't think partial views can set this value, try inspecting your applications response with Fiddler2, after calling Response.SetCookie.

I usually set my cookies with plain Javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I am actually setting the cookie in a controller and trying to read it in the partial view - so maybe the issue is something else after all.  Again just to clarify, its when I try to read a cookie that is not being set on that server trip - it clears the cookie that was set on the previous trip.  So confused....